# Simple algebra, finding x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How and why did the sign + and - switch places in the solution?

### Question:

$$\frac{x-6}x - \frac6x = \frac{x-6}{x+6}$$

### Answer:

#### Step one

$$\frac{x-6-6}x = \frac{x+6}{x-6}$$

[image: equation from textbook]

Comment: probably a typo.

Comment: Ok so how do you solve the original equation?

Comment: @JessicaHam Do the same process by plugging the correct signs.

Comment: I tried... I don't think it works.. Can someone pls try it out

Comment: @PM2Ring , you have found the typo !

Comment: @PM2Ring , congrats !

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. From the previous line, it should be $$\frac{x-12}x=\frac{x+6}{x-6}$$. Can you tell us the name of the textbook this is from?

Comment: To the downvoters: Yes, people should post equations using MathJax. But for suspected typo questions it's very helpful to see an image of the text. It would be nice to have a MathJax transcription as well, but I don't think it's strictly necessary for typos.

Comment: @PM2Ring , I have edited the post.

Answer (score 5):

The original solution is like this :

$$\dfrac{x - 6}{x} - \dfrac 6x = \dfrac{x - 6}{x + 6} \implies \dfrac{x - 12}{x} = \dfrac{x - 6}{x + 6}\\
\implies x(x -6) = (x - 12)(x +6)\\
\implies x^2 - 6x = x^2 +6x-12x-72\\
\implies -6x = -6x - 72\\
\implies 6x = 6x + 72$$

Now that is unsolvable, since $6x-6x = 0 \neq 72$.

Therefore, the actual question must be $\dfrac{x - 6}{x} - \dfrac 6x = \dfrac{x + 6}{x - 6} $.

If this is the question, the solution in the picture is the right solution.

Comment: It looks like you intended to place implies rather than equals signs at the beginning  of the third, fourth,  and fifth lines of your calculations.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, no... I did it deliberately...

Comment: That does not make sense since $x^2 - 6x$ does not equal $-6x$ unless $x = 0$.  Similarly, $-6x$ does not equal $6x$ unless $x = 0$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig , at school I usually do it like that. But you may edit it if you want it to be more clear ':) My mistake.. sorry 'bout it !

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to solve the equation
$$\frac{x - 12}{x} = \frac{x - 6}{x + 6}$$
by corrensponding addition: subtract the numerator from the denominator on both fractions to get
$$\frac{x - 12}{x-(x-12)} = \frac{x - 6}{x + 6-(x-6)}\iff\frac{x - 12}{12} = \frac{x - 6}{12}$$
which is impossible.

NB: The given solution solves
$$\frac{x - 12}{x} = \frac{x + 6}{x - 6}.$$
Using the method above gives
$$\frac{x - 12}{12} = \frac{x + 6}{-12}
\iff x-12=-6-x$$
that is $x=3$.